# How to filter executables using QFileDialog? (Cross-platform solution)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

The [documentation for QFileDialog.getOpenFileName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) does not provide any clue on how to filter only executables using a `const QString &filter = QString()`. Here's the code for my action using PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from os import path


class OpenSourcePortAction(QAction):

    def __init__(self, widget, setSourcePort, config, saveSourcePortPath):
        super().__init__('&Open Source Port', widget)
        self.widget = widget
        self.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        self.setStatusTip('Select a source port')
        self.triggered.connect(self._open)
        self.setSourcePort = setSourcePort
        self.config = config
        self.saveSourcePortPath = saveSourcePortPath

    def _open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self.widget, "Select a source port", self.config.get("sourcePortDir"), "Source Ports (gzdoom zandronum)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            self.saveSourcePortPath(fileName)
            self.setSourcePort(fileName)
```

On linux, naturally, I have no file extensions for executables, but I need to filter .exe extensions on windows (Which I intend to provide a version for). Also, there's no overloaded method that allows [QDir::Executable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html). How can I use `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` while filtering only executables, no matter which platform it's running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a more personalized filter then you have to use a proxyModel but for this you cannot use the getOpenFileName method since the QFileDialog instance is not easily accessible since it is a static method.

```py
class ExecutableFilterModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_index):
        if isinstance(self.sourceModel(), QFileSystemModel):
            index = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, 0, source_index)
            fi = self.sourceModel().fileInfo(index)
            return fi.isDir() or fi.isExecutable()
        return super().filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_index)


class OpenSourcePortAction(QAction):
    def __init__(self, widget, setSourcePort, config, saveSourcePortPath):
        super().__init__("&Open Source Port", widget)
        self.widget = widget
        self.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        self.setStatusTip("Select a source port")
        self.triggered.connect(self._open)
        self.setSourcePort = setSourcePort
        self.config = config
        self.saveSourcePortPath = saveSourcePortPath

    def _open(self):
        proxy_model = ExecutableFilterModel()
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        dialog = QFileDialog(
            self.widget, "Select a source port", self.config.get("sourcePortDir")
        )
        dialog.setOptions(options)
        dialog.setProxyModel(proxy_model)
        if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            filename = dialog.selectedUrls()[0].toLocalFile()
            self.saveSourcePortPath(fileName)
            self.setSourcePort(fileName)
```